# A cauchy sequence question

Tags: convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Let $a_1=\sqrt 2$ and let $n\ge 2$ be defined recursively by the formula

$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{a_n}}$

How can I prove that $a_n$ is a cauchy sequence and conclude that $a_n$ converges?

Comment: @ArnaldoNascimento That would be another sequence, and a much easier one to work with.

Answer (score 0):

One possible path: You may show that the function $f(x)=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{x}}$ is a Lipschitz contraction of $I=[\sqrt{2},2]$, i.e. $f(I)\subset I$ and $\forall x,y\in I: |f(x)-f(y)|\leq L|x-y|$ for some $L<1$ (one may here take e.g. $L=1/8$).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: prove that the sequence is monotonically increasing and bounded.